# HP DL380 G6 SSD only as HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2016

I bought a used HP ProLiant DL380 G6. After installing Windows Server 2016 and running it a few months, I noticed a dramatic slowdown eventhough it is not running 24/7 and it does not have a load of software on it. I have a Samsung SSD 850 EVO build in and booting Windows from it. But Windows seems to recognize it as a HDD. In the Defrag window it says "HDD". The Sata/Sas ports are directly connected to the mainboard. I do not have any extension card in it. Do I have to buy the P410 Smart Array controller to use the full speed of the SSD or is it just a wrong Bios setting? In the Smart Array P410i Controller Menu. The SSD is listed under "Assigned Physical Drives" as "Sata SSD". So why does Windows think it is a HDD?

Comment: From the computers point of view, the disk is pretty much an HDD - it presents as a HDD interface.   You do not need a P410 controller for the disk to work at performance.

There may be firmware issues on the drive and /or the OS may not be enabling TRIM on the drive.

Comment: I just did a quick read speed test via HDtune. The SSD had a max. read speed of 70 MB/Sec. Isn't that a bit low for a SSD, And the OS is the newest so wouldn't it a bit outdated if it didn't enable TRIM?

Comment: 70mb/sec is slow even for a hard drive.

Comment: Yes, that is way below the theoretical speed. I just tried to activate the write cache in the windows settings, but windows does not allow it as it does not recognize the SSD correctly. Additionally I have a 1 TB HDD as data storage but even for that, I cannot active the write cache. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Im not a Windows person but I posit you can't activate the write cache because you don't have a battery associated with a controller?

Comment: sry to reactivate this old thread but it keeps bothering me. It seems that you can enable the non-battery write cache in the p410i raid controller. So I enable the Write-Cache in the Bios but I am not sure if it is the correct setting. Can please someone help me to check whether the non-battery write cache is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Enter raid controller bios settings, while bootinf press F8. There you can see whether battery is Ok. And you can udjust settings, try to enable "write through cache" for your ssd. In your case raid controller see SSD drive but dont show it as SSD to Windows. It show SSD to Windows as vortual drive.